# Amazon pay not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, amazon-payment

I should to make possible to choose "Amazon pay" in checkout, when you choose payment method. But i cant setup "Amazon pay" in Sales->Payment Method. Everything what i do, does not make changes. I try it on 2.2.4 clean project and 2.2.5.
So, how to setup "Amazon pay" that it appear in checkout?

Comment: Have u configured seller central?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have to create an account here https://sellercentral.amazon.in/ and then you will get the necessary credential to activate amajon payment.

Comment: Yeah, i filled all credentials and validate their - all ok